# Getting accessibility right for HTML tables

Tags: html, html-table, accessibility, wcag, wcag2.0

I have a data table used in a page that needs to meet [WCAG 2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20/) AA accessibility standards, but I am being told by my client that the table is not meeting basic accessibility standards.

My client is using an online service called [Cynthia Says](http://www.cynthiasays.com/) which throws up all kinds of errors. So I ran an equivalent test using another service from Total Validator, which suggested everything was OK. Obviously in addition to this I have read much of the guidelines, but I still don't feel that I have enough clarity to go back to the client and reassure them or to make the fix I need.

So far as I understand `<summary>` is deprecated in HTML5 and although potentially useful not a requirement of W3C standards.

The only other thing I can think of would be adding a scope to the `<th>` or possibly `<td>` elements but so far as I can tell from documentation on this (http://www.w3.org/TR/WAI-WEBCONTENT/wai-pageauth.html#tech-table-headers), in this context simply having a `<th>` should do the job.

I have included some example markup below and would appreciate any pointers:

```
<table>
    <caption>
    This is a caption
    </caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Day</th>
            <th>Time</th>
            <th>Lesson</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody> 
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="3"><strong>Monday</strong></td>
            <td>19:00 - 19:45</td>
            <td>Lesson 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>18:00 - 19:00</td>
            <td>Lesson 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>19:00 - 20:00</td>
            <td>Lesson 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="4"><strong>Tuesday</strong></td>
            <td>09:15 - 09:45</td>
            <td>Lesson 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>17:45 - 18:15</td>
            <td>Lesson 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>18:15 - 18:45</td>
            <td>Lesson 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>19:00 - 20:00</td>
            <td>Lesson 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2"><strong>Wednesday</strong></td>
            <td>18:00 - 19:00</td>
            <td>Lesson 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>19:00 - 20:00</td>
            <td>Lesson 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="4"><strong>Thursday</strong></td>
            <td>07:30 - 08:00</td>
            <td>Lesson 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>18:00 - 19:00</td>
            <td>Lesson 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>19:15 - 19:45</td>
            <td>Lesson 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>19:45 - 20:15</td>
            <td>Lesson 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="3"><strong>Friday</strong></td>
            <td>07:15 - 07:45</td>
            <td>Lesson 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>15:30 - 17:00</td>
            <td>Lesson 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>18:00 - 19:00</td>
            <td>Lesson 3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Do you mean **WCAG 2.0** *AA* with "AA accessibility standards"?

Comment: @unor yes that one, sorry for not being clear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The day cells:

```
<td rowspan="3"><strong>Monday</strong></td>
```

are headers and should use `th` elements instead of `td`:

```
<th scope="rowgroup" rowspan="3">Monday</th>
```

and since you have a two axis table, `scope` should be added to the headers in the `thead`:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">Day</th>
        <th scope="col">Time</th>
        <th scope="col">Lesson</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

See [WCAG 2, H63: Using the scope attribute to associate header cells and data cells in data tables](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H63.html) for an explanation.

Comment: Thanks stevax I had a feeling adding `scope="col"` for the main headings would form part of the answer, but I didn't know that the day cells also formed a header. Although that does seem obvious now you point it out. 

In the page you refer to it also says "Check that all td elements that act as headers for other elements have a scope attribute." Does that mean that the days cells could also be written code `<th scope="rowgroup" rowspan="3"><strong>Monday</strong></th>`?
I know that's not semantically correct, but just checking if it's plausible.

Comment: Ah no, hold on. Just thinking about that last question. Probably shouldn't try that as that would be appropriate in a different context, with perhaps `td`s spanning other cells within the main body of the table.

Comment: @CraigCooper the `strong` elements shouldn't be needed on the row headers, I've updated the answer to reflect that.